# How to use a rule mark on the quartiles of the x axis to display the corresponding y axis value

Tags: visualization, vega-lite

#### Problem

I have a distribution of IDs each with a ratio value. I'd like to use vega-lite to display the cumulative number of IDs that are at or below a given ratio. I'd also like to visually display the quartile boundaries on the x-axis with text that show the corresponding y-axis value.

I've gotten stuck on figuring out how to display the quartile boundaries and the corresponding ratio values. Fundamentally it's a question of how to aggregate the data.

#### Example Images

**[Where I'm at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOxXl.png)**, using a combination of `window` and `joinaggregate` transforms. It displays the area and quartiles but no text.

**[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njLRq.png)**, using fake data. It displays the area, quartiles, and text.

Any help would be appreciated.

#### Current code

##### Where I'm at using transforms

[vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGhA1lCgE5r2AHVkA2AAwOATDYDMdhQEZrLjzcd2-BwU7SjFrABYxGzExR0dg6wBOH3DwmwB2dy9ZD3CPZLio4Mobaw9HDxdEysqE2RiosRd-cOLHMpsPdJd08MSxNut0x370gA5K9LqfRzHe5tbs2LHE3rG3YrGxsvKPDztK9xCxRKG7SMTUu0TixO36uzGbG3Xwqez0xIqxMbth2-ashcsWirjymyG4RceWu-WKvSGbh6MU6dUcP1+-neOx6b2qHmKTWsEz+jiqVTqfXRHjG4Ts8RCp1kcSeqVcUzs1k6fUiXQG2QqIz6qxcdXyNhhlTGdQmdwCj3iSwleUqkU2gNWfQm4UcHJ2lxWYih8OydzpXX8ouOihAADM2KZkJg0KBMABPHBwQxQCDEEAAX39SgA7sZ6GgxEEQJhzLIIPbHWgANqgGSmZ2oFN2mhwQTKQzmTDsAMAXRDNFkyjYweToDYOAL1YA+rIGAgmHBTDakAZ0ABhNsMQQWUgAAgAkspR322AxZM7-SWg6BJGwK0gyGRTHxMF7M3WG+gAI4eG22nN5gsWNjd3sgQvsJs4dEBhQHwwIODKGhIeRKc+5vm6APjeSg9leRZsE+kavu+x4uGeF5Afe163hBj44OkYiwSA9aGCeiGAYYA4IEOI5wBOU4znOzpgXeUDGE2UCzvOT4vsuuGHiAn7fr+hGXv2g7DkWY6TtOLG0SA4HoAxyhMRJ0F2DheHwfxyEkWRIkUWJ1HzmhMmMcxNFPlhpaLkow5up2tbcUgpgANaGHZcAoEocCyMx36yGQLogG6vkAQJKGQTa7qevhDC-kW6haa+IAAB4BUhxFCeRlHiTRoUenuIBHpF850ORNrQDoe6gLINBQHuto6BAcCBoGb62Q5BZDl6bkeWwXk+ZoCVJURBlyUZrHPthShhTleVRYVsUNU1yAtcBbU2u5nkVj1oCJb1gXIbJ8nGTgMHjdlEXTTFNCkAGjWgAtjlLYI7UgKtXXrb5W2gDt3qGQpmFjdGJ3Hvl0VFQ1S5AA)

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": "id,ratio\n60002630,1\n316206200,0.5\n4565522,0\n93144670,1\n141932256,0.6\n121391313,0\n555653204,0.2\n161737495,0.2\n729578137,0\n312874324,1\n528974830,0.88\n112110130,0.59\n704594409,0.98\n508668347,1\n792158072,0.92\n352656341,0.8\n743410995,0.74\n730375561,0\n25880207,1\n113747911,0.53\n810723939,0\n492518402,0.9\n228644637,0\n614945175,1\n212949973,0\n196410138,0\n819806082,1\n564411345,0.82\n974981427,0\n119489543,0.71\n984017203,0.5",
    "format": {"type": "csv"}
  },
  "width": 500,
  "transform": [
    {
      "sort": [{"field": "ratio"}],
      "window": [{"op": "row_number", "as": "Cumulative Id Count"}]
    },
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {"op": "q1", "field": "ratio", "as": "ratio_p25"},
        {"op": "median", "field": "ratio", "as": "ratio_p50"},
        {"op": "q3", "field": "ratio", "as": "ratio_p75"},
        {"op": "q1", "field": "Cumulative Id Count", "as": "cid_count_p25"},
        {"op": "median", "field": "Cumulative Id Count", "as": "cid_count_p50"},
        {"op": "q3", "field": "Cumulative Id Count", "as": "cid_count_p75"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "area",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "ratio", "type": "quantitative"},
        "x": {
          "field": "Cumulative Id Count",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"nice": false}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "cid_count_p25", "type": "quantitative"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "cid_count_p50", "type": "quantitative"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "cid_count_p75", "type": "quantitative"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

##### Using fake data to show what I'd like to have

[vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGhA1lCgE5r2AHVkA2AAwOATDYDMdhQEZrLjzcd2-BwU7SjFrABYxGzExR0dg6wBOH3DwmwB2dy9ZD3CPZLio4Mobaw9HDxdEysqE2RiosRd-cOLHMpsPdJd08MSxNut0x370gA5K9LqfRzHe5tbs2LHE3rG3YrGxsvKPDztK9xCxRKG7SMTUu0TixO36uzGbG3Xwqez0xIqxMbth2-ashcsWirjymyG4RceWu-WKvSGbh6MU6dUcP1+-neOx6b2qHmKTWsEz+jiqVTqfXRHjG4Ts8RCp1kcSeqVcUzs1k6fUiXQG2QqIz6qxcdXyNhhlTGdQmdwCj3iSwleUqkU2gNWfQm4UcHJ2lxWYih8OydzpXX8ouOihAADM2KZkJg0KBMABPHBwQxQCDEEAAX39SgA7sZ6GgxEEQJhzLIIPbHWgANqgGSmZ2oFN2mhwQTKQzmTDsAMAXRDNFkyjYweToDYOAL1YA+rIGAgmHBTDakAZ0ABhNsMQQWUgAAgAkspR322AxZM7-SXF0pVOoIHBML3QLakABrOD8KBsdsVuDKfirjRZgcIIcjuATqczucZ6UgQvF1AEkDDjuCNB2EGoA3neRZjpO06zvOaC+EoH5sDBSi-rmAElEBIAgcOYEPhBz7QagZJwRYCFfkhSB-qh-SLkGIBwLIR7KBWZAuiAbosbaOZ5gWxE2u6nqGAAjgwSDznQ94BkoAAe7Gcfm-aDlhNDgU+UHOkofFeugQkiUW6jYTa0A6JpoCyDQUCaTugjroG6lwJJGauh6mkgLIx4VjoNocbmck-uRKE2b5bqdrWIDIKYu6GEgphwCg6GXixshIAgzk7vuh7Hkwp7nvFNFhRFmjRk5BZDl6NmgPFBWJclhipQeR4nrIZ4XmosVKHlLEaYYmB2WpKhsag-BiIGS5AA)

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": "id,ratio\n60002630,1\n316206200,0.5\n4565522,0\n93144670,1\n141932256,0.6\n121391313,0\n555653204,0.2\n161737495,0.2\n729578137,0\n312874324,1\n528974830,0.88\n112110130,0.59\n704594409,0.98\n508668347,1\n792158072,0.92\n352656341,0.8\n743410995,0.74\n730375561,0\n25880207,1\n113747911,0.53\n810723939,0\n492518402,0.9\n228644637,0\n614945175,1\n212949973,0\n196410138,0\n819806082,1\n564411345,0.82\n974981427,0\n119489543,0.71\n984017203,0.5",
    "format": {"type": "csv"}
  },
  "width": 500,
  "transform": [
    {
      "sort": [{"field": "ratio"}],
      "window": [{"op": "row_number", "as": "Cumulative Id Count"}]
    }
  ],
  "datasets": {
    "fake-combined-data": [
      {"Cumulative Id Count": 8, "ratio": 1, "label": 0},
      {"Cumulative Id Count": 16, "ratio": 1, "label": 0.6},
      {"Cumulative Id Count": 23, "ratio": 1, "label": 0.95}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "ratio", "type": "quantitative"},
    "x": {
      "field": "Cumulative Id Count",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"nice": false}
    },
    "text": {"type": "nominal", "field": "label"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": "area"},
    {"data": {"name": "fake-combined-data"}, "mark": {"type": "rule"}},
    {"data": {"name": "fake-combined-data"}, "mark": {"type": "text", "dy": -5}}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? Wasn't sure if you wanted label or value as the text so I have shown both. In your example, you are plotting dozens of lines BTW so I have aggregated to a single line.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": "id,ratio\n60002630,1\n316206200,0.5\n4565522,0\n93144670,1\n141932256,0.6\n121391313,0\n555653204,0.2\n161737495,0.2\n729578137,0\n312874324,1\n528974830,0.88\n112110130,0.59\n704594409,0.98\n508668347,1\n792158072,0.92\n352656341,0.8\n743410995,0.74\n730375561,0\n25880207,1\n113747911,0.53\n810723939,0\n492518402,0.9\n228644637,0\n614945175,1\n212949973,0\n196410138,0\n819806082,1\n564411345,0.82\n974981427,0\n119489543,0.71\n984017203,0.5",
    "format": {"type": "csv"}
  },
  "width": 500,
  "transform": [
    {
      "sort": [{"field": "ratio"}],
      "window": [{"op": "row_number", "as": "Cumulative Id Count"}]
    },
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {"op": "q1", "field": "ratio", "as": "ratio_p25"},
        {"op": "median", "field": "ratio", "as": "ratio_p50"},
        {"op": "q3", "field": "ratio", "as": "ratio_p75"},
        {"op": "q1", "field": "Cumulative Id Count", "as": "cid_count_p25"},
        {"op": "median", "field": "Cumulative Id Count", "as": "cid_count_p50"},
        {"op": "q3", "field": "Cumulative Id Count", "as": "cid_count_p75"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "area",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "ratio", "type": "quantitative"},
        "x": {
          "field": "Cumulative Id Count",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"nice": false}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "text": "cid_count_p25", "dy": -10},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "cid_count_p25", "aggregate": "max"},
        "y": {"datum": 1}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "cid_count_p25",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "max"
        }
      }
    },
     {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "dy": -10},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "cid_count_p50", "aggregate": "max"},
        "y": {"datum": 1}, "text":{"field": "cid_count_p50"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "cid_count_p50",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "max"
        }
      }
    },
        {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "text": "cid_count_p75", "dy": -10},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "cid_count_p75", "aggregate": "max"},
        "y": {"datum": 1}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "cid_count_p75",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "max"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Davide! Sorry I wasn't clear. What I'm trying to do is (1) Rank all the IDs based on their corresponding metric (in my sample data the metric is a precomputed ratio) and graph this out, (2) Display a vertical rule at the 25th/50th/75th percentiles of the rankings, (3) At the top of each vertical rule, display the metric for that percentile of ranking. [Here's a clarified version of the "what I want" picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcKsX.png). I'd like to display the value of `x` where it intersects with the value of `y`.

Comment: Are the quartiles correctly calculated already? i.e. is the only change to my solution, the value of y for the label? Did you confuse your x and y in your new example?

Comment: Ah yes, changing the value of `y` for the labels to `"y": {"datum": 1}, "text": {"field": "ratio_p50"}` did it. [In picture form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g43Zy.png). Thanks!